# Laravel 5.1 - Join through multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following tables:

```
Customer
    id

Order
    id
    customer_id

Order_notes
    order_id
    note_id

Notes
    id
```

If I want to get all order notes for a customer so I can do the following, how can I do it? Is there way to define a relationship in my model that goes through multiple pivot tables to join a customer to order notes?

```
@if($customer->order_notes->count() > 0)
    @foreach($customer->order_notes as $note)
        // output note
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: you only want it over your model?

Comment: Well not necessarily, just want to know what the best way to do it would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just did the following:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function order_notes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Order_note', 'App\Order');
    }
}

class Order_note extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }

    public function note()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Note')->orderBy('notes.id','desc');
    }
}
```

Then access the notes like so:

```
@foreach($customer->order_notes as $note)
    echo $note->note->text;
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Create these relationships on your models.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function order_notes()
    {
        // have not tried this yet
        // but I believe this is what you wanted
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Note::class, Order::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Order extends Model
{
    public function notes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Note::class, 'order_notes', 'order_id', 'note_id');
    }
}

class Note extends Model
{

}
```

You can get the relationships using this query:

```
$customer = Customer::with('orders.notes')->find(1);
```

Comment: I dont think this is quite what I want since this returns all of the orders individually and then notes against each order. I just want one bug object that respresents all of the customer order notes

Comment: That's exactly what @sumpreto's code is doing. You just need to use `@foreach($customer->notes as $notes)` and you're good to go.

Comment: @geoffs3310 I've added a method under the Customer model. Haven't tried it yet but I think it might work.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) to the correspondent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'belongsToMany' ?
E.g. something like

```
$customer->belongsToMany('OrderNote', 'orders', 'customer_id', 'id');
```

Of course, it'll not work directly, if you want to get order object also (but maybe you can use `withPivot`)